# .NET Event in Powershell not handled until end

Tags: c#, powershell, events

It's quite straight forward question. I've got a dll that's responsible for reading tons of files. Every file completion is indicated by event. Console application handles it correctly displaying info from args as soon as it comes up.

From the other hand I want to run this dll from powershell script and display progress bar. It doesn't work as expected. **Progress bar is displayed in the very end of execution quickly raises within miliseconds from 0 to 100% and dissapears.**

```
$isVerbose = $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Verbose"].IsPresent

$finder = New-Object ContentFinder.LogFinder

if($isVerbose)
{
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $finder -EventName "FileQueueProgress" -Action {Write-Progress ($EventArgs.Percent)} -SourceIdentifier "FileReadingProgressIndicator" | Out-Null
}

try
{
    $path = GetPath
    $date = GetDate

    return $finder.GetErrorLogs($path, $date)
}
catch
{
    Write-Host ($_.Exception.Message)
}
finally
{
    if($isVerbose)
    {
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "FileReadingProgressIndicator"
    }

    Write-Host "Done"
}
```

and it's called like this: `Get-ErrorLogs -Verbose`. Usually I assign it to variable just to be able to filter results and all that works. **Is there something I can do to make PS respond to the events same moment they raise?**

**EDIT: ANSWER** from the comments
This works just as expected. Reports progress during execution, not at the end of script.

```
if($isVerbose)
{
    $Handler = {Write-Progress ($args[1].Percent)} -as $finder. PSObject. Members. Match('FileQueueProgress')[0]. Value. EventHandlerType; 
    $finder. add_FileQueueProgress($Handler); 
    #Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $finder -EventName "FileQueueProgress" -Action {Write-Progress ($EventArgs.Percent)} -SourceIdentifier "FileReadingProgressIndicator" | Out-Null
}

try
{
    $path = GetPath
    $date = GetDate

    return $finder.GetErrorLogs($path, $date)
}
catch{
    Write-Host ($_.Exception.Message)
}
finally
{
    if($isVerbose)
    {
        #Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "FileReadingProgressIndicator"
        $finder. remove_FileQueueProgress($Handler)
    }

    Write-Host "Done"
}
```

Comment: How does `GetErrorLogs` works? Is it blocking to the end of operation? Is `FileQueueProgress` raised in the same thread where `GetErrorLogs` called?

Comment: Yes it runs synchronously and events are raised on the same thread in the meantime.

Comment: How does the console version compare to the PowerShell version?  I would think the behavior you see is expected.  You have nothing asynchronous in the PowerShell, so everything will get queued up. At least that is how I understand it.

Comment: `Register-ObjectEvent ...` -> `$Handler = {Write-Progress ($args[1].Percent)} -as $finder. PSObject. Members. Match('FileQueueProgress')[0]. Value. EventHandlerType; $finder. add_FileQueueProgress($Handler)`; `Unregister-Event ...` -> `$finder. remove_FileQueueProgress($Handler)`

Comment: And thats @PetSerAl is the wonderful answer that solved my problem. Thanks :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In single threaded scenario you actually do not need to use `Register-ObjectEvent`. PowerShell allows you to convert script blocks into delegate type objects. And you can attach/detach that delegates to/from event by calling event accessor (`add_EventName`/`remove_EventName`) directly.

```
$finder = New-Object ContentFinder.LogFinder

if($isVerbose)
{
    $Handler = {Write-Progress ($args[1].Percent)} -as $finder.PSObject.Members.Match('FileQueueProgress')[0].Value.EventHandlerType
    $finder.add_FileQueueProgress($Handler)
}

try
{
    $path = GetPath
    $date = GetDate

    return $finder.GetErrorLogs($path, $date)
}
catch
{
    Write-Host ($_.Exception.Message)
}
finally
{
    if($isVerbose)
    {
        $finder.remove_FileQueueProgress($Handler)
    }

    Write-Host "Done"
}
```

Note: I save delegate object to `$Handler` variable, so I can properly detach it later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code snippet analog to `Register-ObjectEvent` for adding "native" events.

```
function Register-NativeEvent {
    param($Instance, $EventName, [ScriptBlock] $ScriptBlock)

    $handler = $ScriptBlock -as $instance.PSObject.Members.Match($EventName)[0].Value.EventHandlerType
    $handlerMethod = "add_$EventName"
    $instance.$handlerMethod($handler)

    return $handler
}

function Unregister-NativeEvent {
    param($Instance, $EventName, $handler)

    $handlerMethod = "remove_$EventName"
    $instance.$handlerMethod($handler)
}
```

Use `$args[0]` (equals sender) and `$args[1]` (equals event args type of the handler) to acces values.
For example:

```
$handler = Register-NativeEvent $MyInstance "MyEventName" { Write-Host $args[1].MyProperty }
```

and unregister when done:

```
Unregister-NativeEvent $MyInstance "MyEventName" $handler
```